# Android SurfaceView Mirror camera

Tags: matrix, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera-intent

I want to mirror a preview in a rear camera. Not to rotate a view but flip the view.
I am using **surfaceView**. any help will be Appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can flip the image of bitmap using **prescale** properties of Matrix.
example:

```
val rotateMatrix = Matrix() rotateMatrix.postRotate(0.0f) 
 rotateMatrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f)

val rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap, 0, 0, PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT, rotateMatrix, false)
```